# Facebook conversion pixel and google tag manager

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-tag-manager

I am not an engineer but im asking question beyond my understanding. The company i work for recently reported that the Google Analytics often gave us wrong statistics. When i tried to scrawl the website's HTML code , I found that the facebook conversion pixel code was put ahead of the google tag manager code on our website. Does that affect how google analytics work ?  In my mind, google analytics suggests us not to put other tracking code to interfere GA.

Answer (score 0):

While it defeats the purpose of tag management systems to have tags outside the tag management container Google Analytics will work just fine with other tracking pixels, and Google certainly does not say anywhere that you should not use other tracking software. Nobody would use GA if it interfered with the normal operations of a website.

So no, the Facebook Pixel will not interfere with GA. You can easily check if the data is transmitted correctly if you use the Chrome extensions that Google provides - look for "[Google Tag Assistant](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?hl=en)", that's the most userfriendly option. Install it via the Google Play Store, it will add a small icon to the right of your adress bar, and if you click the icon you can enable it for any given domain. It will display an error via a red icon if something is wrong, and will give some detailled information about what is being sent to the Google Analytics tracking server. That might help you to find the actual error if there is a problem with data collection (it will not help you to find configuration problems).